# Need to display fields in a different format

Tags: views

I have following fields in my content type:

Title: [some value]
Year: [2011,2012,2013,2014,2014,2016]
Volume: [01,02,03,04,05]
Issue: [1,2,3,4,5]
Description: [some text]

### And I want a output display like the below Format.

OUTPUT:

2013
Volume 01: Issue 1,  Issue 2

2012
Volume 01: Issue 1,  Issue 2,  Issue 3

2011
Volume 01: Issue 1,  Issue 2,  Issue 3

---

All Issues will be hyperlinked. If I click 'Issue 1' under year '2013' it should take me to a page where all posts having value 2013, Volume 01, Issue 1 should be displayed.

How this is done using Views in Drupal 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the above implementation

create a view with url  issue/arg(1)/arg(2)/arg(3)

where 
arg(1) = year 
arg(2) = volume
arg(3) = issue

like above u can pass argument

then by using contextual filter u can filter the view content and show the specific issue u want to.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
I couldn't understand "create a view with url". I couldn't find this option in views.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a page type view

then under **PAGE SETTINGS** tab there is path option add **path** as issue/%/%/%

then by using contextual filter u can filter the view content and show the specific issue u want to.

while hitting the url u need to use issue/year(num)/volume(num)/issue(num)

Comment: Hello Anup, Thanks for the reply. I tired by using the following methods:

Comment: So, I got the following results: 
http://ijamscr.com/sites/all/themes/ijamscr/screenshots/screen1.jpg
http://ijamscr.com/sites/all/themes/ijamscr/screenshots/screen2.jpg

Comment: Hey Anup, since I didn't had option of adding more comment at that time. I have created new question in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76864/need-desired-output-using-views

Please help